# How to Validate email and password through login Api in node js

Tags: node.js

I just started learning nodejs now, I written api for login, I encrypted password by using bcrypt npm. Now what I want is I want to validate email and password.
Logic should be like this: How are registered only they are eligible to log in, And given password should also match. This password wants to be same when he registered

These two conditions want to match other it have show error messages in console like this
If the email address is wrong it have to show, User not found
If he entered a wrong password, then it has to show, please enter a valid password
If both are correct, it has to show User logged successfully.

If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

This is my code

This is login api

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);
    req.body.password = hash
    console.log(req.body)


    const loggedUsers = new Login(req.body);

    try {
        const result = await loggedUsers.save();
        res.json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'sorry something went wrong' })
    }
})
```

These are the npm's I installed and required

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
require('./models/db');
const Jobs = require('./models/job');
const Users = require('./models/user')
const Login = require('./models/login')
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

This is database db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/jobsdb', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

This is schema login.js

```
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);


const loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}
})


const Login = mongoose.model('login', loginSchema)
module.exports = Login
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/login', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```